# Azure SDK for Python: How to limit results in list_blobs()?

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-sdk-python

How can the number of blobs returned from [`ContainerClient.list_blobs()`](https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/python/azure-storage-blob/12.0.0b5/index.html#id20) method can be limited?

The Azure [Blob service RESP API docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/list-blobs) mentions a `maxresults` parameter, but it seems it is not honored by `list_blobs(maxresults=123)`.

Comment: Try the `results_per_page` options: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/sdk/eventhub/azure-eventhub-checkpointstoreblob-aio/azure/eventhub/extensions/checkpointstoreblobaio/_vendor/storage/blob/aio/_container_client_async.py#L541

Comment: @rdas...You're correct about the parameter but you used incorrect link. Would you mind posting your comment as an answer using this link: https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/python/azure-storage-blob/12.0.0b5/_modules/azure/storage/blob/_container_client.html#ContainerClient.list_blobs

Comment: @rdas...I was about to post this as an answer but I saw your comment hence I am not posting an answer :).

Answer (score 1):

A combination of `itertools.islice` and the `results_per_page` parameter (which translates to the REST `maxresults` parameter) will do the trick:

```
import itertools

service: BlobServiceClient = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(cstr)
cc = service.get_container_client("foo")

n = 42
for b in itertools.islice(cc.list_blobs(results_per_page=n), n):
    print(b.name)
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use by_page() on the [ItemPaged class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.containerclient?view=azure-python#list-blobs-name-starts-with-none--include-none----kwargs-)

```
pages = ContainerClient.list_blobs(maxresults=123).by_page()
first_page = next(pages)
items_in_page = list(a_page) #this will give you 123 results on the first page
second_page = next(pages) # it will throw exception if there's no second page
items_in_page = list(a_page) #this will give you 123 results on the second page
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do this currently with the SDK. The `maxresults` parameter really means "max results per page"; if you have more blobs than this, `list_blobs` will make multiple calls to the REST API until the listing is complete.

You could call the API directly and ignore pages after the first, but that would require you to handle the details of authentication, parsing the response, etc.

Comment: @GauravMantri-AIS I don't see how pointing to a `results_per_page` arg shows this is incorrect

Comment: OP is looking for an equivalent of `maxresults` (available in REST API) in Python SDK. `results_per_page` does exactly that.

Comment: @GauravMantri-AIS: What is incorrect?  I am looking for a way to limit results from `list_blobs()`